# IIS redirect users to another server

Tags: http, redirect, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two IIS instances running on different servers with identical code base. The application that runs on these servers reads from a same SQL database. I was wondering if sending users from one server to another possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create iis rewrite rule to then rewrite to specific server within a server farm

for your instance you will use "rewrite" instead of "rewrite to server farm"

check this link to see how to setup rewrite action (ARR as a Forward Proxy)

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing